# Icons in Listview with custom adapter dont change when an option is selected

Tags: java, android, adapter

I made a custom adapter that displays objects in Listview and an icon for each item in list. There are 3 icons that show next to an item in the list view. User can select option "Kupljeno" which changes Status of object to 1, option "Nije kupljeno" to 0 and "Nije dostupno" to 2. Each number represents a different icon, you can that in getView() function of Adapter class. The adapter class looks like this:

```
public class ListaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Proizvod> {

public ListaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Proizvod> proizvodi) {
    super(context, 0, proizvodi);
}

public void remove(int position) {
    this.remove(getItem(position));
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Proizvod proizvod = getItem(position);

    if(convertView==null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shoppinglista_prikazproizvoda,parent,false);

        TextView t = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        t.setText(proizvod.toString());

        switch(proizvod.getStatus())
        {
            case 0:
                t.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.mipmap.ic_nijekupljeno, 0);
                break;
            case 1:
                t.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.mipmap.ic_kupljeno, 0);
                break;
            case 2:
                t.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.mipmap.ic_nedostupno, 0);
                break;
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

You can see that I set icon of each item in getView().

The user should be able to change Status of each Proizvod object with a context menu and when the user chooses object Status, the list should update and show the appropriate icon.

My Proizvod class is this:

```
public class Proizvod {

private int id;
private String naziv;
private int kolicina=1;
private double cijena;
private String lista;
public int status=0;    //0 - nije kupljeno, 1 - kupljeno, 2 - nedostupno

public Proizvod() {
}

public Proizvod(int id, String naziv, int kolicina, double cijena, String lista, int status) {
    this.id = id;
    this.naziv = naziv;
    this.kolicina = kolicina;
    this.cijena = cijena;
    this.status = status;
}

public String getNaziv() {
    return naziv;
}

public void setNaziv(String naziv) {
    this.naziv = naziv;
}

public int getKolicina() {
    return kolicina;
}

public void setKolicina(int kolicina) {
    this.kolicina = kolicina;
}

public double getCijena() { return cijena; }

public void setCijena(double cijena) {
    this.cijena = cijena;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLista() { return lista; }

public void setLista(String lista) { this.lista = lista; }

public int getStatus() { return status; }

public void setStatus(int status) { this.status = status; }

@Override
public String toString() {
    if(this.kolicina==1) {
        return this.naziv + " ["+ this.kolicina +" komad, ukupno " + this.cijena + " kn ]";
    }
    else {
        return this.naziv + " ["+ this.kolicina +" komada, ukupno " + this.cijena + " kn ]";
    }
}
```

}

The code for context menu and changing icon (activity):

```
public class KreiranjeListeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Proizvod> ShoppingLista = new ArrayList<Proizvod>();

EditText nazivProizvoda;
EditText kolicina;
EditText cijena;
Button dodaj;
Button ocisti;
Button spremi;

ListView lista;
ListaAdapter adapter;

//Funkcija vraća ukupan iznos svih stavki u listi
public void AzurirajUkupniTrosak() {

    DecimalFormat zaokruzi=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    double ukupniIznos=0;

    for(Proizvod p : ShoppingLista)
    {
        ukupniIznos+=p.getCijena();
    }

    String ukupniIznosString=zaokruzi.format(ukupniIznos);
    TextView prikazUkupnogIznosa=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_ukupaniznos);
    prikazUkupnogIznosa.setText("Ukupno: " + ukupniIznosString + " kn");
}

//Funkcija otvara meni dužim pritiskom na stavku u listi i nudi opciju brisanja stavke
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.shoppinglista2_list) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) v;
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        Proizvod proizvod = (Proizvod) lv.getItemAtPosition(acmi.position);
        menu.add(200,201,1,"Obriši");
        menu.add(200,202,2,"Kupljeno");
        menu.add(200,203,3,"Nije kupljeno");
        menu.add(200,204,4,"Proizvod je nedostupan");
        menu.add(200,205,5,"Zatvori prozor");
    }
}

//funkcija u kojoj se sa adaptera briše odabrana stavka, iste promjene se automatski primijene i na listu
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 201:
            adapter.remove(info.position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            AzurirajUkupniTrosak();
            return true;
        case 202:
            ShoppingLista.get(info.position).setStatus(1);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case 203:
            ShoppingLista.get(info.position).setStatus(0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case 204:
            ShoppingLista.get(info.position).setStatus(2);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kreiranje_liste);

    final DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);

    nazivProizvoda=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nazivproizvoda_text);
    kolicina=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.kolicinaproizvoda_text);
    cijena=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cijenaproizvoda_text);
    dodaj=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dodaj_gumb);
    ocisti=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ocisti_gumb);
    spremi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.spremi_gumb);

    lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.shoppinglista2_list);

    registerForContextMenu(lista);

    adapter = new ListaAdapter(this,ShoppingLista);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    dodaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /////////////PROVJERE KOD UPISA ///////////////////////

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(nazivProizvoda.getText())) {
                nazivProizvoda.setError("Unesite naziv proizvoda!");
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(cijena.getText())) {
                cijena.setError("Unesite cijenu!");
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(kolicina.getText())) {
                kolicina.setError("Unesite količinu!");
                return;
            }

            if((kolicina.getText().toString()).contains(".")) {
                kolicina.setError("Unesite ispravan broj!");
                return;
            }

            /////////////PROVJERE KOD UPISA -KRAJ ////////////////////////

            DecimalFormat zaokruzi=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            Proizvod p = new Proizvod();
            p.setNaziv(nazivProizvoda.getText().toString());
            p.setKolicina(Integer.parseInt(kolicina.getText().toString()));
            String ukupnaCijena=zaokruzi.format(Float.parseFloat(cijena.getText().toString())*Integer.parseInt(kolicina.getText().toString())).toString();
            p.setCijena(Double.parseDouble(ukupnaCijena)); //množi se količina sa cijenom jednog komada proizvoda
            ShoppingLista.add(p);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            AzurirajUkupniTrosak();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Proizvod dodan u listu!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            nazivProizvoda.setText("");
            kolicina.setText("");
            cijena.setText("");

        }
    });

    ocisti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ShoppingLista.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            AzurirajUkupniTrosak();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Proizvodi su obrisani!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    spremi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get prompts.xml view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(KreiranjeListeActivity.this);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.spremanje_liste, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    KreiranjeListeActivity.this);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText nazivListe = (EditText) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.nazivListe);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Spremi",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                    ShoppingLista shoppinglista = new ShoppingLista(nazivListe.getText().toString(),"TEST DATUMA");

                                    /////POSTAVLJANJE UKUPNOG IZNOSA U NOVOSTVORENU LISTU
                                    DecimalFormat zaokruzi=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                                    double ukupniIznos=0;
                                    for(Proizvod p : ShoppingLista)
                                    {
                                        ukupniIznos+=p.getCijena();
                                    }
                                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                    db.dodajListu(shoppinglista);

                                    for(Proizvod p : ShoppingLista)
                                    {
                                        db.dodajProizvod(p,nazivListe.getText().toString());
                                    }

                                    Intent i = new Intent(KreiranjeListeActivity.this, PopisListaActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Otkaži",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

The problem is that the icons don't change at all. The value of Status of a selected object changes but the icon doesn't, even though I use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); What's wrong?

Comment: where is the code in which you are preparing your list which you have initialized in your ListAdaptor constructor:
public ListaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Proizvod> proizvodi) {
    super(context, 0, proizvodi);
}

Comment: @sumit updated and added whole code from activity.

Comment: @BernardPolman your icons are not changing when performing onClick event on your `TextView`?

Comment: @Yupi the icons don't change but value of Status does.

Comment: Do you have your project on GitHub or somewhere I will take a look?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here change this in your code in your List adapter class:

First create a list of type Proizvod 
List<Proizvod> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

then
public ListaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Proizvod> proizvodi) {
    super(context, 0, proizvodi);
this.dataList = proizvodi;
}

In place of Proizvod proizvod = getItem(position);

use 

Proizvod proizvod = dataList.getItem(position);


Hope it helps!!!
```

Comment: just to be sure try printing your list in your ListaAdaptor class once you initialize it. The problem with your current code is you're not using the data you saved in the list. when you're calling proizvod.getStatus in your adaptor class it'll always give you zero as you've initialized in your class:
public int status=0;

Comment: no, it doesn't give me always zero. I can change the value of Status through the context menu but the icon stays the same, thats the problem.

Comment: Try printing value of proizvod.getStatus() just before this line switch(proizvod.getStatus()) and share what value you're getting